# Filter git diff by type of change

Tags: git, diff

Is there a way to limit `git diff` to changed files?

I'd like to see the differences between two commits, but exclude paths that don't exist in one or the other (additions/deletions).  The following Perl one-liner illustrates most of what I want:

```
git diff master.. | perl -lnwe 'print unless /^(new|deleted) file/../^diff/ and not /^diff/'
```

But that leaves `diff --git a/path b/path` lines for the files that were new or deleted.  Plus it'd be much nicer if I didn't have to parse (also fails if any hunk contains anything matching /^diff/, for example).

Another alternative I tried was:

```
git diff --name-status (args) | perl -lnwe 'print if s/^M\s+//' | xargs git diff (args) --
```

Its output is better, but it still feels hackish.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You are looking for `--diff-filter=M` to show only files **M**odified between the two branches.

From `man git-diff`

> `--diff-filter=[ACDMRTUXB*]`
>
> Select only files that are
>
> - `A` Added
> - `C` Copied
> - `D` Deleted
> - `M` Modified
> - `R` Renamed
> - `T` have their type (mode) changed
> - `U` Unmerged
> - `X` Unknown
> - `B` have had their pairing Broken
> - `*` All-or-none
>
> Any combination of the filter characters may be used.
>
> When `*` (All-or-none) is added to the combination, all paths are
> selected if there is any file that matches other criteria in the
> comparison; if there is no file that matches other criteria, nothing
> is selected.
>
> Also, these upper-case letters can be downcased to exclude. E.g.  `--diff-filter=ad` excludes added and deleted paths.

Comment: Please avoid a stupid error of mine when using --diff-filter=AMR to omit deleted files: If you are removing a file 'x' then git diff HEAD HEAD~1 --name-only --diff-filter=AMR will still list 'x'. Why? Because _from_ HEAD _towards_ HEAD~1 the file was added, not removed.

Comment: Description for T is confusing. From `man git diff` "have their type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, ...) changed (T),"

Comment: If you want to use use `R` (renamed files) you need to use the `-M` expanded it is known as `--find-renames`

Comment: where are these different types documented? basically, A, D, M, T, and R are straightforward I'd love to know what C, U, X, and B imply.

Comment: Nice and another answer point out that lowercase means exclusion. Very handy to exclude deleted files.

Answer (score 32):

As Git 2.10 (Q3 2016) will remind us, there is an easier way to "show everything except added/deleted files." (actually since Git 1.8.5, July 2013)

```
 git diff --diff-filter=ad master..
```

See [commit 16726cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16726cfa0c3ad5d0d261bd7068014e659cb989da) (14 Jul 2016) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2f8c654](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f8c654edb0c8805749c60228ad9abb5984fba63), 08 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `diff`: document `diff-filter` exclusion

> In v1.8.5 days, [7f2ea5f (`diff`: allow lowercase letter to specify
> what change class to exclude, 2013-07-17)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f2ea5f0f2fb056314092cce23202096ca70f076) **taught the "`--diff-filter`"
> mechanism to take lowercase letters as exclusion**, but we forgot to
> document it.

So [the documentation on `diff-options`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16726cfa0c3ad5d0d261bd7068014e659cb989da/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L402-L404) now (finally) includes:

> These upper-case letters can be downcased to exclude.
> E.g. `--diff-filter=ad` excludes added and deleted paths.

Make sure to use **[Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71190099/6309)**.

Answer (score 6):

To see all modified and new files you can use

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR PREV_VERSION master
```

`PREV_VERSION` is the hash of your first commit.

To get an export as zip you can use this code

```
git archive --output=export.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR PREV_VERSION HEAD)
```

Note: `.gitignore` is not in `export.zip`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the --diff-filter flag to do precisely this. `git diff --diff-filter=CMRTUXB master..` should show everything except added/deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Notepad++ (Windows), and these regular expressions to filter out extension types and certain paths from a diff file.

```
^Index.*\.(dll|pdb|exe|txt|zip|log|ism|resx|tlog|htm|lib)$[\s\S.]*?^Index
^Index: Shared/.+$[\s\S.]*?^Index
^Index: Next/source/Utility/.+$[\s\S.]*?^Index
```

Only problem is, when it reaches the end. You have to 'ctrl+home' and go again until it finds nothing.

(Replace whats found with 'Index')