# What does git add --intent-to-add or -N do and when should it be used?

Tags: git

On `git add -h` I can see the following option:

```
-N, --intent-to-add   record only the fact that the path will be added later
```

But I don't understand when should this option be used. What does this option really do, and how it should be used?

Comment: "*record only the fact that the path will be added later*". In typical Git fashion, the help text isn't very clear, though the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html#_options) explains it *a little* better (but not a whole lot better).

Comment: To hand-wavingly summarize a bunch of arguments in the comments below: It's a fairly advanced feature, and is unlikely to be useful unless you have very specific requirements for your workflow which happen to need it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Enable diffing of untracked files

[Blue112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329124/456814) is *partially* correct. `git add --intent-to-add` does indeed add an empty file to the staging area/index for each specified untracked file in your working copy, **but one of the main purposes of this is to enable you to use** `git diff` **with files that haven't been added to the Git repository yet** by diffing your untracked file against its empty version in the staging area:

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt
$ git diff foo.txt

$ git add --intent-to-add foo.txt
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   foo.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   foo.txt

$ git diff --staged foo.txt
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29

$ git diff foo.txt
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index e69de29..257cc56 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+foo
```

Once you've diffed the file, you can add the non-empty version to the staging area/index by simply doing a normal `git add`:

```
$ git add foo.txt
```

### Enable `git commit -a` of untracked files

Likewise, since `--intent-to-add` makes untracked files "known" to Git by adding empty versions of those files to the staging area/index, it also allows you to use `git commit --all` or `git commit -a` to commit those files along with your known modified files, which is something that you wouldn't be able to do otherwise.

As explained in the [official Linux Kernel documentation for `git commit`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> using the `-a` [or `--all`] switch with the *commit* command [will] automatically "add" changes from all known files (i.e. all files that are already listed in the index)...and then perform the actual commit

### Documentation

From the [official Linux Kernel `git add` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html#_options):

> ```
> -N
> --intent-to-add
> ```
>
> Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files with `git diff` and committing them with `git commit -a`.

Comment: Your answer is correct and makes sense, so +1. However `--intent-to-add` doesn't seem useful to me. Say i have a new file foo.txt with 100 lines of code. When i  `git add -N foo.txt`, and run `git diff foo.txt`, i see 100 lines of added code. (Seems like this is equivalent to cutting all the file's contents, adding the file, then pasting it back into the file.) Now when I make a change—say add a line—and git diff again, i now see 101 lines of added code. So adding an empty filepath to the stage doesn't help in terms of viewing diff.

Comment: @chharvey It depends on your workflow. The behavior you want you can get just by staging the file and ignoring this new option. I like seeing _all_ code I've written when I type `git diff` so I can self-review everything in one place before committing and opening a PR.

Comment: I often stage by patching in iteractive mode and without ``-N`` it would be impossible to patch newly added files.

Comment: I have 3 files `test1 test2 test3`, test1 is committed and since modified, test2 is added using `git add` and test3 is added using `git add -N`. When I run `git commit --all` all 3 files are included in the commit. So I don't understand your point about "enabling git commit --all"

Comment: @Olsgaard the author meant that `git add -N` enables you to use `git commit -a` and commit an untracked file, which it technically still is, even after `git add -N`. You couldn't commit untracked files otherwise with `git commit -a`.

Answer (score 13):

[user456814's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347875/4436482) explains very well what `git add -N` is useful for. I just want to give a more detailed explanation of what's going on in the background.

You can think of git as maintaining a history of file changes like creations, modifications, and deletions (let's call them *deltas*). The deltas are pretty self-explanatory up until the most recent commit, but things get more complicated when you're working in your project to *prepare a new commit* to go on top. There are **three** different types of deltas when you're in this situation.

(Side note: most people, when first introduced to git, are taught something like "committing in git takes two steps; first you do `git add` and then you can do `git commit`". While this is true, it only brings attention to the *Changes to be committed* type of delta. Understanding `git add -N` requires understanding the other types of deltas as well.)

### #1: Changes to be committed

Commonly called "staged changes", these deltas appear **at the top** when you run `git status`, if there are any. If your shell supports color, they will be green.

When you `git add` a file, it gets promoted into this category. These are the changes that will actually be included if you run `git commit` without any flags.

### #2: Changes not staged for commit

These deltas appear **second** when you run `git status`, if there are any. If your shell supports color, they will be red.

These are changes that you have made to files in the git repository **that have not yet been committed AND have not been moved to #1**. When you edit a file and then save, it appears in this category by default.

For a file to show up in this category, it has to EITHER **already exist in the most recent commit**, OR **be added if the changes in #1 were to be committed**. Otherwise, it will show up in category #3.

(Note: because you choose when to "promote" a file into category #1, it's possible to have the same *file* show up in both #1 and #2. For example, I could see

```
modified:   abc.txt
```

in green in #1, and

```
modified:   abc.txt
```

in red in #2 at the same time. This can happen if I promote a file to #1, then later make some more changes to it. The entry in #1 references the delta that I made before promoting the file, maybe adding a new line of code, and the entry in #2 references the delta that I made afterwards, maybe adding a comment at the top. If I were more organized, I would have made all the changes before promoting the file to #1, in order to avoid this situation altogether.)

### #3: Untracked files

These deltas appear **last** when you run `git status`, if there are any. If your shell supports color, they will be red.

These are all the files that are not in the most recent commit AND not in #1. While technically a delta in the sense that adding it would change the commit, it's possible that the file has just always been there and people just don't want git to record any information about it. (In this case, you should add the file to .gitignore, and it will stop showing up in `git status`.)

When you create a brand-new file, it shows up in this category.

## So what does all this have to do with `git add -N`?

`git add -N` is all about making it easier to work with #3 deltas. As referenced in the accepted answer above, `git diff` lets you see what deltas you have actually prepared. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127000/4436482) is a good set of commands that work with `git diff`.

`git diff` only shows the differences between #1 and #2 (i.e. the deltas in #2).

`git diff --staged` only shows the deltas in #1.

`git diff HEAD` only shows the deltas in #1 and #2, put together.

Notice that none of these commands even look at #3. However, by running `git add -N`, you basically do the following:

- Split a new file into two deltas: just file creation, and filling the file with text/content
- `git add` the "file creation" delta into #1

This has the effect of making the second delta appear in #2. Now the new file is completely out of #3, and you can use `git diff` commands with it.

As for `git commit -a`, essentially what it does is:

- `git add` everything in #2 so that it is also staged with everything in #1
- `git commit` (which takes everything in #1, including the stuff that was just added, and creates an actual commit from it)

Without `git add -N`, this command misses your new file in #3; however, you can see that after running `git add -N`, your new file is spread across #1 and #2, and will get included in the commit.

---

Well, I've explained everything I want to explain. If you want to check your understanding, you can follow along with the example below:

1. I make a new git repo.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ cd ~/Desktop
   sh-4.1$ mkdir git-demo
   sh-4.1$ cd git-demo
   sh-4.1$ git init
   Initialized empty Git repository in /local/home/Michael/Desktop/git-demo/.git/
   ```
2. `git status` shows me this repo is empty.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git status
   On branch master

   Initial commit

   nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
   ```
3. I make some new files.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ echo "this is the abc file" > abc.txt
   sh-4.1$ echo "this is the def file" > def.txt
   sh-4.1$ echo "this is the ghi file" > ghi.txt
   ```
4. `git status` shows me all the new files are currently in category #3.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git status
   On branch master

   Initial commit

   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

       abc.txt
       def.txt
       ghi.txt

   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
   ```
5. `git diff` does nothing, since it doesn't operate on #3.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git diff
   ```
6. I commit one file, add another one, and `add -N` the third one.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git add abc.txt && git commit -m "some commit message"
   [master (root-commit) 442c173] some commit message
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
    create mode 100644 abc.txt
   sh-4.1$ git add def.txt
   sh-4.1$ git add -N ghi.txt
   ```
7. In `git status`, `abc.txt` no longer shows up, since it has already been committed. `def.txt` only shows up in category #1 since the whole file has been added. `ghi.txt` shows up in categories #1 and #2.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git status
   On branch master
   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

       new file:   def.txt
       new file:   ghi.txt

   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

       modified:   ghi.txt
   ```
8. By running `git diff`, I can show all the deltas listed in #2. The only delta that shows up is that I added a line to `ghi.txt`.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git diff
   diff --git a/ghi.txt b/ghi.txt
   index e69de29..8a8dee2 100644
   --- a/ghi.txt
   +++ b/ghi.txt
   @@ -0,0 +1 @@
   +this is the ghi file
   ```
9. By running `git diff --staged`, I can show all the deltas listed in #1. Three of them show up: creating a new file `def.txt`, adding a line in `def.txt`, and creating a new file `ghi.txt`. Even though there are 2 deltas for `def.txt`, the file name itself is only output one time in example 7 above, to avoid clutter.

   ```
   sh-4.1$ git diff --staged
   diff --git a/def.txt b/def.txt
   new file mode 100644
   index 0000000..48baf27
   --- /dev/null
   +++ b/def.txt
   @@ -0,0 +1 @@
   +this is the def file
   diff --git a/ghi.txt b/ghi.txt
   new file mode 100644
   index 0000000..e69de29
   ```

Comment: Nice example and explanation. +1

Comment: What's the point of `git add -N file && git diff` when you can just simply do `git add file && git diff --staged` instead??? I still don't really see the point of `-N`.

Answer (score 3):

It is mainly used to add an empty file for your commits.

More informations at [Git with intent to add!](https://coderwall.com/p/l99kbw).

Answer (score 3):

Note that before git 2.10 (Q3 2016), `git add -N` can sometime skips some entries.

See [commit 6d6a782](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d6a782fbf83927212f348f91823d886c5cd6d85), [commit c041d54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c041d54a741e516b5a743f4d27532e484f2a05d3), [commit 378932d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/378932d3c3214cf658805af20c4bd101922d8fcd), [commit f9e7d9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9e7d9f8c3e32280418a0bedd9d37f2a0cc2e2b9) (16 Jul 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3cc75c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cc75c10d781572a073d7dbff4e1695b93a89d48), 25 Jul 2016)</sup>

If you have:

```
a-file
subdir/file1
subdir/file2
subdir/file3
the-last-file
```

And you `add -N` everything... then `subdir` files are *not* recorded as i-t-a ("intended to add") entries.

> ### `cache-tree.c`: fix i-t-a entry skipping directory updates sometimes
>
> [Commit 3cf773e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cf773e4264ecc6e9f603a24aeb72cc68b372f96) (`cache-tree`: fix writing cache-tree when `CE_REMOVE` is present - 2012-12-16 - Git v1.8.1.1) skips i-t-a entries when building trees objects from the index. Unfortunately it may skip too much.
>
> If `subdir/file1` is an i-t-a, because of the broken condition in this code, we still think "`subdir`" is an i-t-a file and not writing "`subdir`" down and jump to the-last-file.
>   The result tree now only has two items: `a-file` and `the-last-file`.
>   `subdir` should be there too (even though it only records two sub-entries, `file2` and `file3`).

---

`git status` has improved, with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018, four years laters): after moving a path in the working tree (hence making
it appear "removed") and then adding with the `-N` option (hence
making that appear "added"), `git status` detected it as a rename, but did not
report the  old and new pathnames correctly.

See [commit 176ea74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/176ea747930908669200520ae14f9dbc61cf0d40), [commit 5134ccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5134ccde642ae9ed6a244c92864c26734d100f4c), [commit ea56f97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea56f97749f6ded2b5d41c4c4ba41b53850b2872), [commit 98bc94e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98bc94ec79c789a70fe0b41bdc91b24ab8483063), [commit 06dba2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06dba2b0235293e84157a59fa22dc89baa336166), [commit 6de5aaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6de5aafdd12104df3d10ef54ac74723a41174290) (27 Dec 2017) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
Helped-by: [Igor Djordjevic (`boogisha`)](https://github.com/boogisha).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 12accdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12accdc023f2b62109860cb745bdd1827b2c22de), 27 Feb 2018)</sup>.

Reminder: `ita` or `i-t-a` stands for "intended-to-add", what `-N` does.

> ### `wt-status.c`: handle worktree renames
>
> Before [425a28e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425a28e0a4edfc39585cec6b0b6368c0ad9dbf7e) (`diff-lib`: allow ita entries treated as "not yet exist
>   in index" - 2016-10-24, Git 2.11.0-rc0) there are never "new files" in the index, which essentially disables rename detection because we only detect renames when a new file appears in a diff pair.
>
> After that commit, an i-t-a entry can appear as a new file in "`git diff-files`". But the diff callback function in `wt-status.c` does not
>   handle this case and produces incorrect status output.