# why `git diff` reports no file change after `git add`

Tags: git, git-diff, git-add

### Why is that `git diff` thinks there are no changes

..even if `git status` reports them as *modified*?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   file-added
    modified:   file-with-changes   << it knows there are changes
```

but in order to see the difference, I need to explicitly add the last reversion hash..

```
$ git diff
  (nothing)

$ git diff rev-hash
diff --git a/file-with-changes b/file-with-changes
index d251979..a5fff1c 100644
--- a/file-with-changes
+++ b/file-with-changes
.
..
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Please try `git diff --staged` command.

Alternative options available are listed below.

> `git diff`

shows changes between index/staging and working files. Since, in your case, `git add` moved your `files-with-changes` to staging area, there were no modifications shown/seen.

> `git diff --staged`

shows changes between HEAD and index/staging. `git diff --cached` also does the same thing. `staged` and `cached` can be used interchangeably.

> `git diff HEAD`

shows changes between HEAD and working files

> `git diff $commit $commit`

shows changes between 2 commits

> `git diff origin`

shows diff between HEAD & remote/origin

Answer (score 5):

`git diff` diffs against the index, not against your `HEAD` revision.  By running `git add`, you've put the changes in your index, so of course there are no differences! Use

- `git diff HEAD` to see the differences between your tree state and the `HEAD` revision, or
- `git diff --cached` to see the differences between your index and the `HEAD` revision.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same problem.

- Add the new file that you created using git add filename1.c
- Make another change in some other filename2.c that was already a part of the repository tracking system.
- Do a git diff and you will only see the change to filename2.c show up. Changes to filename1.c will not show up.
- However if you do a git status you will see the changes in both filename1.c and filename2.c show up.
- Do a git commit -a -m "Changes to filename1.c and filename2.c blah blah"
- Do a git push

You will see that filename1.c got committed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `git diff` by default checks differences between the staging area and your working copy. When you `git add`, your staging area matches your working copy and therefore diff reports no changes.

Adding the `--cached` flag tells diff to diff against `HEAD`.