# Git: Apply Diff of New File

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, diff

I had a script that, for each changed_file in

```
"git diff --name-only master..origin/master"
```

the diff for that file is applied like the following:

```
git diff master..origin/master file_name | git apply.
```

For any newly creately files (files in origin master but not originally in master), I got the following errors:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'my_file_name': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

error: unrecognized input
```

Upon searching on SO, I found the following information on the intent-to-add flag of git add: [What does git add --intent-to-add or -N do and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329051/what-does-git-add-intent-to-add-or-n-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

So I tried the following: for each file I'm about to get a diff of between origin/master and master, if that file doesn't currently exist in master (local), then I call git add with --intent-to-add flag prior to calling git diff with that filename and applying the diff.

```
if ! ls "$changed_file" 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo adding new file "$changed_file"
        echo foo > "$changed_file"
        git add --intent-to-add "$changed_file"
fi
git diff master..origin/master "$changed_file" | git apply
```

With this, I'm getting the following error when trying to do the git apply (last line), saying the file already exists in working directory:

```
error: tests/new_file: already exists in working directory
```

When I tried removing the dummy file creation part, like the following, it also didn't work.

```
if ! ls "$changed_file" 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo adding new file "$changed_file"
        git add --intent-to-add "$changed_file"
fi
```

with the error message being the same as before:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'my_file_name': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

error: unrecognized input
```

Does anyone know what's going on, and how I can fix this? (get and apply diff of NEW remote file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in general, Git doesn't know if `file_name` is a *file* name, or a *branch* name, or what.  The solution is to *tell* it: after a double dash `--`, *nothing* can be an option or branch name:

```
git diff --name-only master origin/master -- file_name
```

The same rule applies to commands like `git checkout`.  What if you have a file named `master` and you want to check it out?  The command:

```
git checkout master
```

won't work, but the command:

```
git checkout -- master
```

*will*, because the two dashes tell `git checkout` that this is the end of options and branch names and such: everything else *must* be a file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard origin/master      # reset index, worktree and ref
git reset --soft @{1}               # put the ref back
```

is all you need.

Comment: Good stuff. Sometimes the best way to fix a bug is not to write the code, eh?