# Is it possible to force git diff to act on the working tree literally including new files without changing the index?

Tags: git

Consider the following sequence of commands, which does the following:
1.Creates two branches (`master` and `test_branch`), where `master` has two commits, and `test_branch` has one commit.
2. The final state is that `test_branch` is checked out, but the working directory should match the tree at the tip of master exactly.

```
git init .
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial commit'
echo FOO > FOO.txt
git add FOO.txt
git commit -m 'Added foo'
git checkout -b test_branch HEAD^
git status
git checkout master -- .
git reset
git diff master
```

The output of this sequence of commands is the following:

```
diff --git a/FOO.txt b/FOO.txt
deleted file mode 100644
index b7d6715..0000000
--- a/FOO.txt
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-FOO
```

However, my working directory has `FOO.txt` with exactly the contents that `git` claims are missing:

```
cat FOO.txt
FOO
```

**Is there some alternate invocation of `git diff` or lower level command that will force it to take the literal working tree and compare it with a commit, instead of pretending the untracked files in the working tree do not exist for the purposes of comparison?**

Comment: You can use `git add -N .`. Then your untracked files will be present in the diff. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/855767/14967413

Comment: It looks like this approach changes the index, so perhaps it's not possible to do it without changing the index. I'll post my silly workaround in that case.

Comment: I believe `-N` option only modifies the index in the way that affects `git diff` and `git commit -a` commands as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347875/14967413. Normal `git commit` should not be affected.

Comment: @user14967413, After running `git add -N .`, I can no longer run `git stash`:
```git stash
error: Entry 'FOO.txt' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
Cannot save the current worktree state```

Comment: The fact that it records a zero-length blob in the main index is still different from the desired entirely zero-index-modification state, and it can cause weird side effects like this, which we can try to workaround, but I think ultimately causes enough unexpected problems that it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my current read of the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index), it seems like there's no way to perform this diff without adding the working directory to *some* index.

Therefore, I will continue to use the following hack, which adds the working tree to a secondary index file without touching the default index file. Note that the script deliberately excludes files that are ignored by `.gitignore`, since I do not care about diffing files I've explicitly ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_COMMIT="HEAD"
if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
  TARGET_COMMIT="$1"
fi

GIT_ROOT="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
GIT_DIR="${GIT_DIR:-$GIT_ROOT/.git}"
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_DIR/.xyz
rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE

git read-tree "$TARGET_COMMIT"
git add "$GIT_ROOT"
git diff --cached "$TARGET_COMMIT"
```