# git stash seems not to work when new files have been added?

Tags: git, command, git-stash

I don't have the exact setup on me right now, but I remember adding a couple of new files to my tree and then wanting to stash them. Instead of stashing correctly, git stash returned an error:

```
error: Entry 'x' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

It seems weird, since the error message has to do with merging, but that's what I got back from git stash.

Does anyone know why and in what circumstances git stash returns an error such as this?

Edit:

In response to the nice people who have answered so far, I'd like to clarify something that I didn't mention originally. After rebuilding the situation in a new git repo, I can say for certain that I wasn't in the middle of a merge and my new files were being tracked. I used `git add -N .` to add the files without staging them, so that I could stash them properly. After trying to stash, I get this error message:

```
error: Entry 'x' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
Cannot save the current worktree state.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the new files you have are not added to the `index` (they are new files) and are not being tracked and you are attempting to stash the changes. You can do this:

```
git add <file1> <file2> ...
```

and the `git stash` should work.

If it doesn't, you can force the index to refresh and try again:

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

Followed by `git stash`.

Comment: I used git add -N . to add the files to the index. I also tried your git update-index --really-refresh command, but that didn't make the error go away. See my edit in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the original answer below, since it applies to most cases, but your question edit changes the answer.  Here's the correct one:  **Don't use `git add -N`.**

The way `git add -N` works is to make a special index entry, that Git is supposed to know what to do with.  For a long time, it was badly broken.  A number of corner cases have been fixed over the last five or so years, and it now works for a lot of cases—but it's still broken for `git stash`, even in Git 2.37:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.37.0.3.g30cc8d0f14
$ touch newfile && git add -N newfile && git stash
error: Entry 'newfile' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
Cannot save the current worktree state
$ git rm newfile
error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    newfile
(use -f to force removal)
$ git rm -f newfile
rm 'newfile'
```

Note that `git add newfile` would have worked, but `git add -N newfile` doesn't.

(It's not clear to me how `git stash` should behave with a `-N` file in the first place, which is probably why nobody else has fixed it either.)

---

#### Original answer

> ```
> error: Entry 'x' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
> ```

This error is ... not a good *message*, but it means you're in the middle of a conflicted merge.  Presumably you recently ran `git merge` or `git rebase` or some other command that *started* a merge.  This command, whatever it was, was *unable to finish the merge*.

Running `git status` now will tell you *which files are unmerged*.  You *must* finish merging them before you can move forward.  Alternatively, you can use `git reset` or another equivalent command to "move backwards" as it were, but you'll lose uncommitted work you have done since the failed merge failed.

If the command that was unable to finish was `git merge`, you can use `git merge --abort`, which is more or less equivalent to `git reset --hard`.  If the command that was unable to finish was `git rebase`, you can use `git rebase --abort`, which is more or less equivalent to `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`.  If the command that was unable to finish was `git stash apply` (perhaps invoked via `git stash pop`), there is no `git stash` command that will clean up, and you may be in fairly deep trouble here.  This is one of several reasons that I suggest Git users (regardless of how beginner or advanced they are) try to avoid using `git stash`: its corner cases can be really miserable.  (Once you're an advanced Git user, you'll know what to do for the most-miserable cases, but that won't make you any happier.  But you'll also know which ones can be the most awful, and know to avoid `git stash` for those.)

My main advice here is: *do not try to use `git stash`*.  Instead, use `git status` to figure out what operation has failed to complete and left you in this conflicted-merge state.  *Finish* that operation, by providing Git with the correct merge result, and use `git merge --continue` or `git rebase --continue` or `git cherry-pick --continue` or whatever is appropriate here based on the operation that's currently half-done.

Depending on how you like to resolve conflicted merges, use `git checkout-index` or `git show` to extract particular file copies from the index—Git's index is where the conflict really "lives"—or just edit the working tree file directly, or use `git mergetool`, or whatever you prefer.  Once you've come up with the correct result, put that in your working-tree file and use `git add` to tell Git that the file now contains the correct result.  **Remember that Git itself has left you with a working tree file that *probably does not have the correct result*** so do not just `git add` the existing working tree file without looking!

(The `git mergetool` command will optionally do the `git add` step for you, if the merge tool you select can tell Git whether you've told the merge tool that the file is now correct.)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Sadly, this doesn't seem to be the answer, since I wasn't in the process of merging at the time. See my edit in my post.

Comment: Aha: you may have a buggy version of Git. Using `git add -N` makes a special entry that, in many Git versions—including the most recent release—doesn't work for some cases. (But for later, remember that you can be in the middle of a conflicted merge without having run `git merge`.)