# git diff option to not show new files?

Tags: git, git-diff

When there's a new file, `git diff` shows a diff between `/dev/null` and the new file, thus showing the whole file as added lines.  Similarly, when a file is deleted, `git diff` diffs it against `/dev/null`, showing every line being deleted.

The `-D` option suppresses that diff for deleted files.

Is there an option to suppress the diff for created files?

(A reasonably careful reading of `git help diff` suggests that the answer is "no", but I'd really like a way, so I'm hoping there's something I missed.)

[Footnote: Yes, I do know how to type `/^diff/` in the pager, to skip to the next diff, but I'd rather not have to.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41730200/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71190099/7976758 . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+ignore+new+files

Comment: `git diff --diff-filter=a`

Comment: @phd Thanks.  Voted to close as dup.  (Silly me, I thought the similar question finder would find a similar question when I posted.)

Comment: `git diff -- ":(exclude)directory-to-exclude"`