# What makes C and R filters in git diff --diff-filter=CR command?

Tags: git

I can't understand what means "Copied" and "Renamed" for git diff-filter, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879568/2039203. When I rename/move some file, than this file is handled as "Added" and "Deleted".

So the question is: what should I do to get some files filtered with the following two commands? Do I need this filter options to get the list of the added/deleted files?

```
git diff --diff-filter=C --name-only
```

and

```
git diff --diff-filter=R --name-only
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question: what do you mean by "Do I need this filter options to get the list of the added/deleted files?"  Are you looking for a list of files that were changed?  Is `git status` not telling you what you want?

Comment: No, I need this list for another purpose. I want to have something like this:
`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A 8b8aeb0 > newFiles`
and than to use this output for my needs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff` will show a file as "renamed" if it passes a "similarity test".  To make sure it's occurring, specify the `-M` option (I'll do that below).<sup>1</sup>

```
$ mkdir /tmp/temprepo && cd /tmp/temprepo && git init
$ cat << end > file
> Here is some text for a file.
> We want it to be long enough
> that renames and copies can
> be detected fairly easily.
> If we put ten lines into the
> file, then each percent of
> similarity is one tenth of
> each of the lines, i.e., each
> line represents 10% similarity
> to the earlier file.
> end
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 842824a] initial
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git mv file newname
$ git diff --cached --name-status
R100    file    newname
```

Let's go ahead and commit this so that we can `git diff` two commits, rather than the commit and the index:

```
$ git commit -m B
[master a2380eb] B
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename file => newname (100%)
```

Just to see what that did:

```
$ git diff --name-status -M HEAD^ HEAD
R100    file    newname
```

Now let's make a minor change:

```
$ ed newname
279
9s/10/about 10/p
line represents about 10% similarity
w
285
q
$ git commit -a -m C
[master 57fce41] C
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git diff --name-status -M HEAD~2 HEAD
R087    file    newname
```

The diff (with `--name-status` mode selected) between `HEAD~2` (the initial commit) and the latest commit now shows that file `file` was renamed to `newname` with only 87% similarity, rather than 100% similarity (as now seen between `HEAD~2` and `HEAD~1`).<sup>2</sup>

To see copies you generally have to run `git diff` with `-C` and/or `--find-copies-harder`.

You can control how similar files must be to have renames (and copies) detected with numeric values after `-M` (and `-C`), e.g., `-M90%` causes the above `git diff --name-status` to treat the rename as an add-and-delete pair:

```
$ git diff --name-status -M90% HEAD~2 HEAD
D       file
A       newname
```

The `-B` option also affects rename detection, as do `git config` settings `diff.renameLimit` and `diff.renames` (see the documentation).  To defeat rename detection entirely—which makes writing git hook scripts with `--diff-filter` a lot easier in many cases—use `--no-renames` (or any of the porcelain commands, which don't obey `diff.renames`; see also footnote 1).

---

<sup>1</sup>This similarity test defaults to "50% similar" when `diff.renames` is enabled and "exact match only" when it is disabled.  In Git versions prior to 2.9, `diff.renames` defaulted to `false` (disabled); in 2.9 and later it defaults to `true` (enabled) and can also be set to `copy` or `copies` to enable the `-C` option as well.  Note that the `diff.renames` setting applies to `git diff`, which is what Git calls a *porcelain* (or user-facing) command, but not to, e.g., `git diff-tree`, which is what Git calls a *plumbing* command.  You must use the `-M` or `--find-renames` option if you want the plumbing commands to do rename detection.

<sup>2</sup>Earlier, we used `HEAD^` and `HEAD`, but we added commit `C` since then, so the initial commit is now `HEAD^^` or `HEAD~2`.

Comment: Thank you. Especially for `--no-renames`.

Comment: Since this answer, I belive the defaults have changed to `diff.renames=true` since `2.9` . Also, I believe `diff.renames=false` does not imply "exact match only", which one of the footnotes implies, see `62df1e68e0086d9d8dc65a76d99f72c265dcf852`

Comment: @CervEd: correct, the default changed in 2.9, I'll update. As for the commit you mention, that's a documentation update meant to clarify that `diff.renames=false` turns it off (which it still does) and that plumbing commands don't use `diff.renames`.

Answer (score 4):

You need a little more than that since copy and rename detection isn't enable by default.

Try this:

```
git init example
cd example
echo foo > foo.txt
echo baz > baz.txt
git add .
git commit -m "add foo and baz"
cp baz.txt other-baz.txt
git mv foo.txt bar.txt
git add other-baz.txt
```

At this point, you should see something like this in `git status -s`:

```
## master
R  foo.txt -> bar.txt
A  other-baz.txt
```

Two things to make note of here: `git status` does rename detection, but it's not doing copy detection.  So it tells you about the rename, but it's showing the copy as an add.  Also, the changes are *staged*.  So a plain `git diff` isn't going to show anything.

To see `--diff-filter=C` and `--diff-filter=R` work, you need to tell `git diff` to do copy and rename detection, and you need to allow it to look at the staging area (called the "index" in the git documentation).  Try this:

```
$ git diff --staged -C -C --diff-filter=C --name-only
other-baz.txt

$ git diff --staged -C --diff-filter=R --name-only
bar.txt
```

In this case, the copy requires specifying `-C` twice to make Git look at previous commits when doing copy detection (since it's the copy of a previously committed file).  You can also use `--find-copies-harder` to enable this behavior.

Comment: Good point about rename detection being off by default; I'll need to tweak my answer just a bit. :-)

Comment: Hrmph.  I thought I had my `diff.renames` setting commented out, but apparently not.  Thanks @SleepWalker.

Comment: Rename is detection is default since `2.9` 2016-ish