# Pulling "delete operation" on files from git branch

Tags: git

I have a branch `A` with certain files in `foo/` in tact, and I have a branch `B` with a number of files in `foo/` deleted throughout a number of commits.

How can I delete same files in `A`'s `foo/` which are deleted in `B`'s `foo/`?

Comment: `git checkout A`, then `git merge . B`

Comment: @vgoff, I'm looking to for merging changes only in `foo` folder though.

Comment: It seems to me that if the commits are atomic, you would be able to cherry pick those deletions into your A branch.

Comment: @vgoff, I tried `git checkout B -- foo/' for `A`, but that doesn't pull deleted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any command on the Git client that does this kind of operation on the index and working tree.  The only command that distinguishes the types of changes is `git diff`, as far as I remember.

You may have to write a script that loops over a diff filtered by deletes (See [Filter git diff by type of change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879568/231573)).

Or if you can use [xargs](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-xargs.html) and pipes it's pretty simple:

```
git checkout A
git diff --diff-filter D --name-only HEAD B | xargs git rm
```

Answer (score 0):

On Branch A

```
git checkout branchB path/to/foo/
```

Comment: I believe this only adds files, but does not remove them.