# List only files with permissions changes in git

Tags: git, file-permissions

How can I list all files in git for which only permission have been changed?

There is `git diff -p --name-only --no-ext-diff`, but this lists all the files with changed permissons, including the ones, that have changed content.

I just want to list the files with updated permissions, excluding the ones with text changes (even if they have updated permissions).

**Edit:**

I'v tried: `git diff --diff-filter=T` as suggested in [Filter git diff by type of change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501) but this returns empty output, even if I still see some files without text changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter git diff by type of change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501/filter-git-diff-by-type-of-change)