# git difftool, winmerge with new files

Tags: winmerge, difftool

I've seen the entries on only showing modified files etc. with difftool but has anyone found a way yet to also show the new files?  I still want to see what someone added as part of the commit, even though it's a new file and not a modification.  Seems like what difftool needs is to create an empty 'dummy' file so that tools like winmerge have something to 'diff' against.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063859/58678) for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I too seek the answer to your problem, but I offer some workarounds until that happens.

You may be able to try the **`--dir-diff`** option, which works alright, but I prefer each change opening in a separate window than having to trawl through directories until I find a difference or a new file.

`git difftool --dir-diff`

Another option I've been doing is to use **winmerge for modified** files and **kdiff for new** files.

`git difftool -t winmerge --diff-filter=M`

`git difftool -t kdiff3   --diff-filter=A`

Note that the above assumes you've setup the different `difftool` options in your `.gitconfig` accordingly.

Not exactly great, but also not a bad workaround. A list of diff filter options is in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), there's also another post here on StackOverflow regarding how to [filter git diff by type of change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501/filter-git-diff-by-type-of-change).

I've also actually just added these as aliases in the `.gitconfig` so that I can just type `git dtm` and `git dta` accordingly.

Comment: Just on the diff filter, you may want to be checking added and deleted files, not just added files... I'd have to check how it handles renames as well, can't remember offhand if winmerge picks it up as a rename or as two separate add and delete operations.