# How to get winmerge to show diff for new file in git?

Tags: git, winmerge, difftool

I can get winmerge to show me diffs for modified file. But for new files, winmerge gives a dialog saying 'Left path is invalid!'. I want it to show the left pane as empty and right pane with the contents of the file.

```
$ git difftool head^ newfile.txt
```

winmerge Dialog:

[image]

I'm on git version 2.8.2.windows.1

This is my git config for difftool:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" -e -ub -wl \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So far, I am seeing this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33369083/6309

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could not find this exact workaround so I'm posting this. Hopefully, someone finds it useful.

I use a `winmerge.sh` script which simply passes an already created empty file for newly added (or removed) file. The script is in a dir that's on my `PATH` or `/git/cmd/` dir for git bash.

**winmerge.sh** (similar to one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116806/58678))

```
#!/bin/sh
# $1 is $LOCAL
# $2 is $REMOTE
NULL="/dev/null"
empty="$HOME/winmerge.empty"
if [ "$2" = "$NULL" ] ; then
    # added
    "D:/setups/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub -wl -wr "$1" "$empty"
elif [ "$1" = "$NULL" ] ; then
    # removed
    "D:/setups/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub -wl "$empty" "$2"
else
    # modified
    "D:/setups/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub -wl "$1" "$2"
fi
```

I keep an empty file `winmerge.empty` at this path `$HOME` (which is `c:/users/<username>`).

I use the `sh` script in `.gitconfig`.

**.gitconfig**

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = winmerge.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

**Note:**

To diff untracked files (new files) also before committing, I do

```
$ git add -N --no-all .
```

then use `difftool`. `-N --no-all` only adds the path of new files to index but not their content (`--no-all` is required to NOT stage the deleted files).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot with a similar issue!