# How to find deleted files in a single commit in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-log, git-show

```
git show -m -1 --name-only --pretty=format: --stat --relative --first-parent commit_id
```

I am using above command to list all the files in a commit. It is listing all the deleted files as well.

I want to remove deleted files from my list.

Is there a way to exclude deleted files from git show command?
Or is there a way to list deleted files from a commit id?

Comment: Please only include relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if adding the [`--diff-filter` option of `git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) helps

```
--diff-filter=ACMRTUXB
```

So anything but "D", which would filter for deleted files.

Shorter version ([since Git 1.8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891447/6309)):

```
 --diff-filter=d
```

The lowercase "d" means: everything but deleted files.

Comment: git show command with --diff-filter=d is not working with specific commit id

Comment: @Asma I just tested it on https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d924528d8bfe947abfc54ee9bd3892ab509c8cd: `git show --diff-filter=D --name-only --oneline 4d924528d8bfe947abfc54ee9bd3892ab509c8cd` does list the deleted file. With 'd', it does list the other added or modified files.

Comment: @Asma With your command, it does work: `git show -m -1 --name-only --pretty=format: --stat --relative --first-parent --diff-filter=d 4d924528d8bfe947abfc54ee9bd3892ab509c8cd`