# git add/rm files based on the type of change (of the files)

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

Is there a way to stage or unstage (`git add` / `git rm`) files only based on what was the type of modification?

Like :

- add/rm only files that are deleted
- add/rm only files that are new
- add/rm only files that are modified
- add/rm only files that are renamed

Comment: I don't think git has a standard way of doing this. You may need to write some bash magic

Comment: @evolutionxbox seems like it , i couln't find anything useful in the git docs either

Comment: This might be helpful? [Filter git diff by type of change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501/filter-git-diff-by-type-of-change) --- use this to list the files, and then add them?

Comment: I've noticed people here don't like questions that have no code... it makes them nervous

Comment: @evolutionxbox As a general StackOverflow rule (that applies more outside the Git questions), if you haven't even attempted your own solution, you shouldn't be posting. :-) I'm not a big downvoter, especially because I tend to answer Git questions, where poor newbies are overwhelmed by Git's massive impenetrability (see https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [other linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501/filter-git-diff-by-type-of-change) you can do (in bash)

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D | xargs git add
```

to e.g. only add deleted files.

You can use the other diff-filter options for modified, new, renamed files etc. And of course you can swap out `git add` for `git reset` etc.

> `--diff-filter=[ACDMRTUXB*]`
>
> Select only files that are
>
> - `A` Added
> - `C` Copied
> - `D` Deleted
> - `M` Modified
> - `R` Renamed
> - `T` have their type (mode) changed
> - `U` Unmerged
> - `X` Unknown
> - `B` have had their pairing Broken
> - `*` All-or-none
>
> Any combination of the filter characters may be used.

Comment: however this worked on my Linux terminal , xargs is not known parameter in windows terminal .

Answer (score 2):

[Steven Fontanella](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70177635/86072) has given most of the answer : `git diff --diff-filter` will allow you to list files which are already tracked by git, or that have already been `git add`ed.

To list files that are on disk but not added yet, you will need to use `git ls-files` :

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -o
```

---

Also, for those cases where files `git` detects a renaming, you will want to either process the specific output of git diff, or use the `--no-renames` option to list such files as a deletion + an added file.